# Force absolute URIs for a specific controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a controller action that generates a template for an online credit card payment gateway (Ogone). I need to force all URIs (image links in the layout, stylesheets, javascripts ...) to be absolute in this case, since the page will be filled up and rendered by the payment gateway server itself.

What is the "rails 3 way" of doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem completely outside of rails, with the use of wget, with option -k, which converts all relative links to absolute links. It my controller, it looks like:

```
def action_with_relative_links
end

def action_with_absolute_links
    render :text => convert_to_absolute_links(:action_with_relative_links)
end

def convert_to_absolute_links(action_param)
  `wget -q -k -O/tmp/absolute_links.html #{url_for :action => action_param}`
  `cat /tmp/absolute_links.txt`
end
```

There is still one little thing to correct in this code: the problem that may arise in high concurrency, because of the use of a temporary filesystem file.

I wish there was a way to avoid that hack, and do everything in rails, but I'm pretty happy with the result, and it permits me to keep all my views and layout files unchanged.

I hope it can help someone!